# Invoke-command using issue

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to run powershell script via invoke-command like below. But I am getting the following the error message. where am I wrong ?

```
$nicMacAddress = "12-34-56-78-90-12"
$nic1MacAddress = "12:34:56:78:90:12"
$nic2MacAddress = "12:34:56:78:90:11"

$code1 = @'
    switch(`$nicMacAddress){

        '$($nic1MacAddress.Replace(':','-'))"' {
         
        write-host "LAN interface edited" -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        
        }

        '$($nic2MacAddress.Replace(':','-'))' {
        write-host "BACKUP interface edited" -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
     

       }

         Default {

            Write-Error 'Unknown MAC address found'

        }


    }

'@

Invoke-Command -ComputerName hostname -ScriptBlock $code1
```

Output  :

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot bind parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Cannot convert the "    switch($nicMacAddress){
        '$($nic1MacAddress.Replace(':','-'))"' {
        write-host "LAN interface edited" -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        
        }
        '$($nic2MacAddress.Replace(':','-'))' {
```

Comment: why are you defining the scriptblock with a here-string? that has never been needed by any code i have used. the code i have seen simply puts the text in scriptblock braces [`{}`] and then uses it.

Comment: ditto to @Lee_Dailey, but also note that inside a scriptblock the variables defined **outside** are not known, unless you either use them in the scriptblock with the `Using scope modifier` (i.e. `$using:nicMacAddress`) or add a `param` block to the scriptblock for these variables and use the `-ArgumentList` parameter to send the variables as parameters to it.

Answer (score 3):

As commented, the easiest way to define a scriptblock is to put the code inside curly brackets `{}`. At the moment, you are putting it inside a Here-String, which simply makes it a string that happens to look like code.

Inside the scriptblock, the variables you have defined outside are unknown, so you need to either send tem trhough as parameters like this:

```
$nicMacAddress  = "12-34-56-78-90-12"
$nic1MacAddress = "12:34:56:78:90:12"
$nic2MacAddress = "12:34:56:78:90:11"

$code1 = {
    param (
        [string]$nic,
        [string]$nic1,
        [string]$nic2
    )
    switch($nic) {
        $($nic1.Replace(':','-')) {
            write-host "LAN interface edited" -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        }
        $($nic2.Replace(':','-')) {
            write-host "BACKUP interface edited" -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
       }
       default {
            Write-Error 'Unknown MAC address found'
        }
    }
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName hostname -ScriptBlock $code1 -ArgumentList $nicMacAddress, $nic1MacAddress, $nic2MacAddress
```

Or (as of PowerShell 3.0) make use of the [using scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7#the-using-scope-modifier)

```
$nicMacAddress  = "12-34-56-78-90-12"
$nic1MacAddress = "12:34:56:78:90:12"
$nic2MacAddress = "12:34:56:78:90:11"

$code1 = {
    switch($using:nicMacAddress) {
        $(($using:nic1MacAddress).Replace(':','-')) {
            write-host "LAN interface edited" -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        }
        $(($using:nic2MacAddress).Replace(':','-')) {
            write-host "BACKUP interface edited" -BackgroundColor DarkRed -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
       }
       default {
            Write-Error 'Unknown MAC address found'
        }
    }
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName hostname -ScriptBlock $code1
```